# Highchart dynamically draw Legend marker and trigger mouseover event

Tags: highcharts

I have series legends as scrollbar as demo-ed in this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kb4gu5rn/

How can I draw series legend marker ("circle"/"square"/"diamond" etc..) instead of line

```
var $line = $('<div>')
  .css({
    width: 16,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: -20,
    top: 8,
    borderTop: '2px solid ' + (series.visible ? series.color :
      options.itemHiddenStyle.color)
  })
  .appendTo($legendItem);
```

Also upon hover in this legendItemList I would like to trigger the mouseOver event on the series.. To highlight the series(or data points) in the chart for easy co-visualization

I added this handler, but it doesnt work

```
$legendItem.hover(function () {
       series.onMouseOver();
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class to add a specific legend marker symbol.

To highlight the series use `setState('hover)`:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart({...}, 

function(chart) {
    var options = chart.options.legend,
        legend = chart.legend;
    /**
     * What happens when the user clicks the legend item
     */
    function clickItem(series, $legendItem, symbolLine, symbolSVG) {
        series.setVisible();
        $legendItem.css(
            options[series.visible ? 'itemStyle' : 'itemHiddenStyle']
        );
        symbolLine.attr({
            stroke: series.visible ? series.color : options.itemHiddenStyle.color
        });
        symbolSVG.attr({
            fill: series.visible ? series.color : options.itemHiddenStyle.color
        });

    }
    // Create the legend box
    var $legend = $('<div>')
        .css({
            width: 110,
            maxHeight: 210,
            padding: 10,
            position: 'absolute',
            overflow: 'auto',
            right: 10,
            top: 40,
            borderColor: options.borderColor,
            borderWidth: options.borderWidth,
            borderStyle: 'solid',
            borderRadius: options.borderRadius
        })
        .appendTo(chart.container);


    $.each(chart.series, function(i, series) {
        // crete the legend item            
        var $legendItem = $('<div>')
            .css({
                position: 'relative',
                marginLeft: 20
            })
            .css(options[series.visible ? 'itemStyle' : 'itemHiddenStyle'])
            .html(series.name)
            .appendTo($legend);

        // create the line with each series color
        var symbolEl = $('<div>');
        var renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
            symbolEl[0],
            16,
            10
        );

        var symbolLine = renderer
            .path([
                'M',
                0,
                5,
                'L',
                16,
                5
            ])
            .attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: series.color
            })
            .add();

        var symbolSVG = renderer.symbol(
                series.symbol,
                3,
                0,
                10,
                10,
                Highcharts.merge(series.options.marker, {
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10
                })
            ).attr({
                fill: series.color
            })
            .add();

        symbolEl.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            left: -20,
            top: 2
        }).appendTo($legendItem);

        // click handler 
        $legendItem.hover(function() {
            chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
                if (s !== series) {
                    s.setState('inactive');
                } else {
                    series.setState('hover');
                }
            });
        }, function() {
            chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
                s.setState('normal');
            });
        });

        $legendItem.click(function() {
            clickItem(series, $legendItem, symbolLine, symbolSVG);
        });

    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mfvh9ubq/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setState

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#symbol